# Running simple Scala in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a very simple hello world Scala program in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac without using the Scala console configuration. I have followed these [steps](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-spark-development-environment-with-scala/) to largely get started, but I didn't set up the debugger outlined there. There isn't a default run configuration enabled, but I can right-click on my source file and select "Scala Console," as we can see here:
[image]

Is there a way to select or edit my configurations to make it so I don't have to use the console? Below are the available configurations.
[image]

I simply want there to be a way to run my Scala code and see the generated output in the provided console, which Scala Console isn't doing. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Lab6` should be an object, not a class.
This will allow you to run it as a main method